# Recursive Mazes: when multiple paths

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

Following is a representation of a maze that I wish to solve using recursion. S is the starting point and F is the finishing point. The numbers on top and left represent the coordinates.

I have written the code but the problem is that when the current position is 3,2 then there are 3 options for next current position: top, left and down.

If I remove the option to go leftward, then it is solved correctly and the output is "Maze not solved" because current positive never reaches F(finishing coordinate).

However, with leftward condition, I get no solution and an infinite loop is run.

[image]

Here's part of the code (only including direction==3 which means if next move will be leftward):

```
bool solveRecursive(char grid[][6],int siz, int curRow, int curCol, int direction,bool check)
{

while(check==0)
{
     if(curRow==4 && curCol==0)
     {
         check = 1;

     }

 else if (direction == 3)   // If open space in west
    {
        //}
        if(grid[curRow][curCol-1] == '.')
        {
            curCol--;
            check = solveRecursive(grid,siz,curRow,curCol,3,check);
        }

        if (grid[curRow-1][curCol] == '.')
        {
            curRow--;
            check = solveRecursive(grid,siz,curRow,curCol, 0,check);
        }

        else if (grid[curRow+1][curCol] == '.')
        {
            curRow++;
            check = solveRecursive(grid,siz,curRow, curCol, 2,check);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
return check;
```

}

Comment: Hi I am just trying to make sense of your question. When you say "the current position is 3,2" do you mean the intersection of column 2 and row three. Unless you otherwise specify a coordinate system I would suggest that you use the cartesian system "x,y" or "column,row" instead of "row,column". I would suggest an edit but cannot due to the min number of characters.

Comment: Also does your program have any bounds checking to stop array overflow?? i.e. `if((curRow >= 5) || (curRow <0) || (curCol >=5) || curCol < 0)) {check = false;}`